# Can't send emails through REST API

Tags: rest-api, email

I'm trying to send an email using `wp_mail()` through a `REST` custom route, but it's failing somewhere.

EDIT: I found out where, in "sendContactMail()", `$request->get_json_params();` returns nothing, although `$request` contains all my form information. What's the right way to extract this information then?

```
// custom route callback function
function sendContactMail(WP_REST_Request $request) {
  $response = array(
    'status' => 304,
    'message' => 'There was an error sending the form.'
  );
  $parameters = $request->get_json_params();
  if (count($_POST) > 0) {
    $parameters = $_POST;
  }
  $siteName = wp_strip_all_tags(trim(get_option('blogname')));
  $contactName = wp_strip_all_tags(trim($parameters['contact_name']));
  $contactEmail = wp_strip_all_tags(trim($parameters['contact_email']));
  $contactMessage = wp_strip_all_tags(trim($parameters['contact_message']));

  if (!empty($contactName) && !empty($contactEmail) && !empty($contactMessage)) {
    $subject = "(New message sent from site $siteName) $contactName <$contactEmail>";
    $body = "<h3>$subject</h3><br/>";
    $body .= "<p><b>Name:</b> $contactName</p>";
    $body .= "<p><b>Email:</b> $contactEmail</p>";
    $body .= "<p><b>Message:</b> $contactMessage</p>";

    if (send_email($contactEmail, $contactName, $body)) {
      $response['status'] = 200;
      $response['message'] = 'Form sent successfully.';
    }
  }
  return new WP_REST_Response($response);
}

// custom route declaration
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'contact/v1', 'send', array(
    'methods' => ['POST','PUT'],
    'callback' => 'sendContactMail'
  ));
});
```

Form-related content of `$request`:

```
["body":protected]=> string(382) "------WebKitFormBoundaryoh45oL7PWjTynEQK Content-Disposition: form-data; name="contact_name" Jack ------WebKitFormBoundaryoh45oL7PWjTynEQK Content-Disposition: form-data; name="contact_email" jack@gmail.com ------WebKitFormBoundaryoh45oL7PWjTynEQK Content-Disposition: form-data; name="contact_message" This is my message. ------WebKitFormBoundaryoh45oL7PWjTynEQK-- "
```

Comment: What is `send_email`? There is no `send_mail` function in the WP function reference, and the closest I can find is `mb_send_mail` over on php.net. Normally `wp_mail` would be used instead. Also, why are you doing all the sanitising and validating in the endpoint? You're meant to add a sanitising and validating function in `register_rest_route`. And why do you use a `$parameters` variable? Instead of `$request['contact_name']`?

Comment: Also, have you confirmed that your server is capable of sending emails? There may be nothing wrong with this code, and instead your emails are being rejected because you sent them from a shared host known for spamming on a domain without anti-spam records

Comment: Also there is no permission callback defined, that rest route will generate PHP warnings in WP v5.6+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*You didn't include the code for your `send_email()` function, but I looked at the original [source](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/revisions/380757/1) (revision 1) of your question, and it seems to me that your `send_email()` function is good, but if this answer doesn't help solve the issue, then add the function code into your question body.*

So I don't know why are you setting your (REST) API endpoint's (HTTP) methods to POST *and PUT*, i.e. `'methods' => ['POST','PUT']`, because I think POST is enough (i.e. `'methods' => 'POST'`), but it seems to me that you are not properly sending your form data to the API endpoint.

And note that, when you use `FormData` (in JavaScript) with the PUT method, both `$request->get_json_params()` and the superglobal `$_POST` are empty, so if you must use the PUT method, then you would want to send your form data as a JSON-encoded string.

Secondly, regardless the (HTTP) method you use, *if you send the data as JSON, then make sure the `Content-Type` header is set with `application/json` being the value*.

So here are two examples using JavaScript, one for each HTTP method, and these examples worked fine for me on WordPress 5.6.0:

### Using `fetch()`, `FormData` and the POST method

```js
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append( 'contact_name', 'John Doe' );
formData.append( 'contact_email', 'john.doe@example.com' );
formData.append( 'contact_message', 'Just testing' );

fetch( 'https://example.com/wp-json/contact/v1/send', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
} )
    .then( res => res.json() )
    .then( data => console.log( data ) )
    .catch( error => console.log( error ) );
```

### Using `fetch()`, `JSON.stringify()` and the PUT method

```js
const formData = {
    contact_name: 'John Doe',
    contact_email: 'john.doe@example.com',
    contact_message: 'Just testing'
};

fetch( 'https://example.com/wp-json/contact/v1/send', {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify( formData ),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
} )
    .then( res => res.json() )
    .then( data => console.log( data ) )
    .catch( error => console.log( error ) );
```

So I hope that helps, and you don't have to use `fetch()` or even JavaScript, but the point in my answer is, make sure your request uses the **proper body/content and content type header**.

## UPDATE

### How to access the request parameters

Please check the [Extending the REST API → Adding Custom Endpoints → Arguments](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#arguments) section in the [REST API handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) for more details, but here are two of the most common ways in accessing the parameters:

- Use `$request->get_params()` to get all the parameters (URL-encoded POST body, JSON payload, URL query string, etc.). So in your case:

  ```php
  // Instead of this:
  $parameters = $request->get_json_params();
  if (count($_POST) > 0) {
    $parameters = $_POST;
  }

  // You could simply do:
  $parameters = $request->get_params();
  ```
- Use direct array access on the object passed as the first parameter to your endpoint callback, i.e. the `$request` variable above. E.g.

  ```php
  $contactName    = $request['contact_name'];
  $contactEmail   = $request['contact_email'];
  $contactMessage = $request['contact_message'];
  ```

And in your case, you should probably just use the second option above.

### Have you tested your `send_email()` function via direct function calls (i.e. not through the REST API)?

Although I don't know what's the code in your `send_email()` function, you should test the function by passing test data and see if the function actually works, e.g. does it return true, false, null, is there any errors/notices, etc. And if it's the function that doesn't work, then the problem is not with the REST API, i.e. even on normal requests like the homepage, that function would not work.

So test your *email sending function*, confirm that it receives all the necessary parameters and that it actually properly sends the email (e.g. use the correct headers like "From" and "Content-Type").

### Always set `permission_callback`, and utilize `validate_callback` and `sanitize_callback` for validating/sanitizing the request parameters

So basically, except for the `send_email()` function, your code does work in that the endpoint gets registered and it returns a good response. But here are some things that you should bear in mind when adding custom endpoints:

1. Make sure to always set a [`permission_callback`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#permissions-callback) for your endpoint, because if you don't set it, then the following would happen (but by default, only if [debugging](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) is enabled on your site):

   > As of WordPress
   > 5.5, if a `permission_callback` is not provided, the REST API will issue a `_doing_it_wrong` notice.

   Sample notice that would be issued:

   > The REST API route definition for `contact/v1/send` is missing the
   > required `permission_callback` argument. For REST API routes that are
   > intended to be public, use `__return_true` as the permission callback.
2. The third parameter for [`register_rest_route()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/) accepts an argument named `args` which is an array of parameters for your endpoint, and for each parameter, you can set a validation callback (`validate_callback`) and a sanitization callback (`sanitize_callback`), so you should use that instead of doing the validation/sanitization in your endpoint's main callback. And here's one of the good reasons why would you want to use those callbacks:

   > Using `sanitize_callback` and `validate_callback` allows the main
   > callback to act only to process the request, and prepare data to be
   > returned using the `WP_REST_Response` class. By using these two
   > callbacks, you will be able to *safely assume your inputs are valid
   > and safe when processing*.

   That was a (slightly reformatted) excerpt taken from the API handbook, BTW.

### Try my code

**Note:** I originally tested your code with a *dummy* `send_email()` function, but here, I'm using [`wp_mail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) directly in the main callback.

```php
// The code is basically based on yours.

function sendContactMail( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    $response = array(
        'status'  => 304,
        'message' => 'There was an error sending the form.'
    );

    $siteName = wp_strip_all_tags( trim( get_option( 'blogname' ) ) );
    $contactName = $request['contact_name'];
    $contactEmail = $request['contact_email'];
    $contactMessage = $request['contact_message'];

    $subject = "[$siteName] (testing) New message from $contactName";
//  $body = "<h3>$subject</h3><br/>";
    $body = "<p><b>Name:</b> $contactName</p>";
    $body .= "<p><b>Email:</b> $contactEmail</p>";
    $body .= "<p><b>Message:</b> $contactMessage</p>";

    $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
        "Reply-To: $contactName <$contactEmail>",
    );

    if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers ) ) {
        $response['status'] = 200;
        $response['message'] = 'Form sent successfully.';
        $response['test'] = $body;
    }

    return new WP_REST_Response( $response );
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'contact/v1', 'send', array(
        'methods'             => 'POST',
        'callback'            => 'sendContactMail',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
        'args'                => array(
            'contact_name'    => array(
                'required'          => true,
                'validate_callback' => function ( $value ) {
                    return preg_match( '/[a-z0-9]{2,}/i', $value ) ? true :
                        new WP_Error( 'invalid_contact_name', 'Your custom error.' );
                },
                'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
            ),
            'contact_email'   => array(
                'required'          => true,
                'validate_callback' => 'is_email',
                'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_email',
            ),
            'contact_message' => array(
                'required'          => true,
                'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_textarea_field',
            ),
        ),
    ) );
} );
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Your code works. One last thing though: wp_mail returns `false` although the content of `$to`, `$subject`, `$body` and `$headers` look OK. Any idea how I could debut this? Within a regular WP site I could use something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715122/how-to-display-wp-mail-errors. But from a non-WP site merely using WP as a headless CMS, I have no clue how to troubleshoot this particular problem. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you could add the REST API endpoint on that WP site, then why can't you do the debugging by hooking on `wp_mail_failed`? You could even do the debugging from within your endpoint/callback. And did `wp_mail()` only return false, but the email actually got sent? If no, then try with a direct call to the native `mail()` function in PHP - and I mean, something super simple like `mail( 'user@example.com', 'test', 'test' )` - does it work?

Comment: And if I were you, I'd check the hosting support pages/docs to see if there's a special setup in sending emails from PHP on sites hosted by them. Also, you could try with plugins like [WP Mail SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) which comes with a feature to send test emails.

Comment: Thanks! WP Mail SMTP is successfully sending a test email, yet `mail('user@example.com', 'test', 'test')` or `mail('user@example.com', 'test', $headers)` (using `$headers` as defined in your code) don't, can't figure out why..

Comment: The first four parameters for `mail()` and `wp_mail()` are the same, i.e. `$to, $subject, $message, $headers` (except `wp_mail()` accepts an array as the 1st parameter), but you actually called `mail()` by setting `$headers` as the 3rd parameter.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what happened when I pasted the code here, I was really doing `mail('fabpallaud@gmail.com', 'test', 'test', $headers);`

Comment: That's strange.. but you can try deactivating plugins and see if there's a plugin is causing the issue. And did you use the default settings in WP Mail SMTP? If not, what did you change? Also, just to confirm: did you try with my exact code? Are you 100% certain your data is good? And if you haven't, try enabling debugging and use the Query Monitor plugin, then see if the logs say anything relevant to the email issue.

Comment: Turns out it WAS working, only the hosting provider was having issues it seems. Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simulate what you did in my test environment.

When I made the AJAX call like this, it worked.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT", //HTTP VERB
    url: "${this.baseUrl}/wp-json/contact/v1/send", //URL
    dataType: 'json', //What type of response you expect back from the server
    contentType: 'text/plain', //What type of data you are trying to send
    data: fromData,
    success: function (response, request) {
        alert(response)
        this.success = true
        this.ApiResponse = respone
    },
    error: function (response, request) {
        alert(response)
        this.success = false
        this.ApiResponse = respone
    }

})
```

My callback function was very simple:

```
function sendContactMail(WP_REST_Request $request) {
  return 'OK';
}
```

Once you get the response in Javascript, you can start debug the callback function.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't really help..