# WP_REST_Response() doesn't seem to return the expected object

Tags: rest-api

Building on [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/381627/11634), the `WP_REST_Response()` object returned by the callback function of my custom route is not the object I'm asking it to return. My object has a "status" of 304 and a "message" field, the object returned has a "status" of 200 and no "message" field. Why?

Below I simplified `sendContactMail()`'s code and created an error response. None of this ends up showing up in the console (see bottom of my question):

```
function sendContactMail(WP_REST_Request $request) {
  $response = array(
    'status'  => 304,
    'message' => 'There was an error sending the form.'
  );

  return new WP_REST_Response($response);
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
  register_rest_route('contact/v1', 'send', array(
    'methods'             => 'POST',
    'callback'            => 'sendContactMail',
    'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
    'args'                => array(
      'contact_name'    => array(
        'required'          => true,
        'validate_callback' => function ($value) {
            return preg_match('/[a-z0-9]{2,}/i', $value) ? true :
              new WP_Error('invalid_contact_name', 'Your custom error.');
        },
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
      ),
      'contact_email'   => array(
        'required'          => true,
        'validate_callback' => 'is_email',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_email',
      ),
      'contact_message' => array(
        'required'          => true,
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_textarea_field',
      ),
    ),
  ));
});
```

Front-end:

```
fetch(`${this.baseUrl}/wp-json/contact/v1/send`, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
})
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.status === 304) {
      // do something
    } else {
      // do something different
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Console:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [`WP_Rest_Response`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_response/) did return the proper response based on what your endpoint callback returns, but I think you just not understanding what `fetch()` returns, so please check the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#concepts_and_usage) for more details, but here's an excerpt that might help you:

> The `fetch()` method takes one mandatory argument, the path to the
> resource you want to fetch. It returns a `Promise` that resolves to
> the
> [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)
> to that request, whether it is successful or not.

So referring to [your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjlDx.jpg), you're actually viewing the above-mentioned `Response` object which includes the body, headers, URL, etc. And the response body is that `body` property there (click the `body: (...)`), but to get the actual JSON data in the response, you can use [`res.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json):

```js
fetch ( `${this.baseUrl}/wp-json/contact/v1/send`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
} )
    .then(
        ( res ) => {
            res.json().then(
                ( data ) => console.log( data, res.status ),
                ( jsonError ) => console.log( jsonError )
            );
        },
        ( error ) => console.log( error )
    );
```

And actually, that `status` in your `$response` array is part of the response **body**, so that `$response` is actually the response body.

If you want to send a custom HTTP status code, you can use the second parameter for [`WP_HTTP_Response::__construct()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http_response/__construct/) which is inherited by the `WP_REST_Response` class which extends `WP_HTTP_Response`.

But, are you sure you want to use the 304 ("Not Modified") status? Because that would return no response *body*.. So you should instead use 400 ("Bad Request") to indicate an error in the request.

```php
function sendContactMail( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    // dummy param, used for emitting an error, if requested
    $ok = empty( $request['is_error'] );

    // Send the response with custom HTTP status code.
    if ( $ok ) {
        return new WP_REST_Response( array( 'message' => 'Form sent!' ), 200 );
    } else {
        return new WP_REST_Response( array( 'message' => 'Something wrong..' ), 400 );
    }
}
```

Or you could also just return a [`WP_Error`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_error/) instance and the status code will default to 400:

```php
function sendContactMail( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    // dummy param, used for emitting an error, if requested
    $ok = empty( $request['is_error'] );

    // Use the default HTTP status codes.
    if ( $ok ) {
        return new WP_REST_Response( array( 'message' => 'Form sent!' ) );
    } else {
        return new WP_Error( 'foo_code', 'Something wrong..' );
    }
}
```